# Why should I pay my ministers?

Tags: tropico-4

In Tropico 4, why should I pay my ministers more than the average unskilled wage (if anything)? These are appointed individuals; they don't *choose* to work so they won't wander off to a better paying job. Healthcare is free, so it won't cause them to die quicker because of poor health because they got sick; and there's nothing *wrong* with living in a shack other than it making them miserable. All that will happen is the job quality will be significantly lowered, and they'll probably be a bit on the unhappy(er) side.

What are the downsides to this strategy? Does wage and/or job quality affect ministers' performance at all?

[image: Ministry management view]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**If you underpay your ministers, they will be less happy**. With low wages, the [job quality](http://tropico.wikia.com/wiki/Job_Quality) of your ministry positions will be low, which means anyone appointed to those positions will be less happy. Since [your citizens will only spend 1/3 of their wages on rent](http://tropico.wikia.com/wiki/Housing), low wages mean they can only afford housing with low rent. If the only housing ministers can afford is low-quality housing (such as [shacks](http://tropico.wikia.com/wiki/Shack_(Tropico_3_and_4))), they will be less happy.

**Even though unhappy ministers might not leave their jobs, [unhappy citizens can do other things you won't like, such as vote against you](http://tropico.wikia.com/wiki/Happiness).**

Comment: Does it affect their job performance at all?

Comment: @RoddyoftheFrozenPeas Not that I'm aware of. Based on everything I was able to find, the frequency and quality of events your ministers create (or cause) are based on their stats.